# In Russian, is [i] a possible substitute for [ɯ] after a velarized consonant?

Tags: фонетика

I've read [i] doesn't really occur in the context I've described but I still want to know whether the meaning is changed.

Comment: while this is on-topic I also can imagine this as a relevant question at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The IPA for Russian Ы is [ɨ], not [ɯ].

This sound does not occur after velarized (soft) consonants in Russian.

Similarly, [i] occurs only after velarized consonants (or at the beginning of a word).

Comment: I... think "velarized" is the opposite of soft, which is "palatalized".

Comment: That is correct. Hard corresponds to velarized whilst soft to palatalized. Also, in Russian, [i] suposedly occurs after a "palatalized" consonant.